# Turn off Openlayers 3 Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, openlayers-3

So, my idea of turning off the Geolocation functionality in an Openlayers 3.9.0 map is to have a toggle button that when is clicked it stops the tracking and removes the feature from the geolocation layer

```
geolocation.setTracking('false');
featuresOverlay.getSource().clear();
```

and then to turn it on again it turns the tracking on, adds a feature to the geolocation layer, sets its coordinates and re-centers the map

```
geolocation.setTracking('true');
featuresOverlay.getSource().addFeature(positionFeature);
var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
view.setCenter(coordinates);
```

Well, this technically does not count as turning on/off the geolocation because it removes all the visual elements, it does not actually turns on/off the API. Is there such a possibility, or the above are enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it does, after one minor change.

Assuming that `geolocation` in your code references an instance of `ol.Geolocation`, calling `geolocation.setTracking(false)` will make the `geolocation` call `clearWatch` on the browsers geolocation API. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.10.1/src/ol/geolocation.js#L134).

However, `setTracking` expects a boolean value. You send the string `'false'`, which is interpreted as a truthy value (since it's a non-empty string). Remove the quotation marks from the `setTracking` paramters, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Most usefull observation ever. Thanks so much